# array.push() but no results in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Link [here](http://tinyurl.com/osldea3).

```
<script>
  dataLayer = [];
</script>

<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXX" // disguised GTM snippet
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-PB4S9P');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->

<script>
  dataLayer.push({
    'event':'nevent',
    'eventCategory': 'form submissions',
    'eventAction': 'saw form',
    'eventLabel': '[GPI - Donation Request Form]'  // e.g. Newsletter signup form - NEW SITE
  });  
</script>
```

When I visit the link and open the console and type dataLayer I expected to see the object. But I cannot.

When I am on the page if I cut n paste the `dataLayer.push({});` it works - I see it added to the `dataLayer`.

So how could it be that the `dataLayer` array is not populated with the contents of the push below it?

Comment: It works for me.  When I visit the page and type `dataLayer` into the console. I get the object.

Comment: The GTM script probably loads after your push method and overwrites your `dataLayer` variable. Try putting it inside some variant of document.ready

Comment: It works for me too.

Comment: @Jan yes I think that's probably the issue. OP that Google thing is simply overwriting the value of your variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The provided code doesn't match the one on your page.
Your page is (somewhat) minified, i.e. it has no line breaks.
This conflicts with your end-of-line-style comment (`//`):

```
<script>  dataLayer.push({    'event':'nevent',    'eventCategory': 'form submissions',    'eventAction': 'saw form',    'eventLabel': '[GPI - Donation Request Form]'  // e.g. Newsletter signup form - NEW SITE  });  </script>
```

It cuts of the `});`, resulting in a syntax error.
Nevertheless though, I **do** get a result for typing `dataLayer` in the console:

```
[
    {
        "gtm.start": 1438884079089,
        "event": "gtm.js"
    },
    {
        "event": "gtm.dom"
    },
    {
        "event": "gtm.load"
    }
]
```

Comment: That's one poor minifier that doesn't remove comments

Comment: @Jan It also doesn't even collapse multiple spaces into one... doesn't break functionality, but makes all other minification basically pointless.

Comment: Thank you so much. Accepting when the time limit comes off. So, how did you spot/realise that? Just so I know how to tell in future?

Comment: Well, visiting the link you posted gives a console error, so I'm guessing that was clue #1 ;) http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info <- Check the "debugging" section

Comment: @DougFirr The Chrome console told me that there's a syntax error, and I saw that your code was minified, so I dropped it into [an HTML beautifier](http://www.cleancss.com/html-beautify/) (just my favourite, not mine or anything), and then I was basically just saw that there's no bracket or anything after an indented block.